# Patch policy for VM mgt (Azure)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have tasked with developing a strategy to patch for all VMs in our TEST subscription, and apply the results to prod down the line..
The plan to create 2 scenarios

1. for all critical,security,Definition updates
2. for everything else
   The plan is to use Azure update mgt center for this.Can anyone recommend this as best practice?Anything else I need to know and plan for?
   Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can able to develop patches for all VMs in your test subscription in your scenarios.

***In your virtual machine -> updates under operations -> open your update management center.***

[image]

As my VM upto date updated you can make use of below workarounds.
Click in ***schedule updates***.   In basic use guest user vm and schedule time as your requirement.

[image]

In VM you can make use of every vm update or selected vm while clicking ***Add machine.***

[image]

In update as your scenario, you can add ***critical, security, Definition updates*** by adding ***include update classification*** as below.

[image]

Now you can able to deploy patches for all VMs in your subscription using Azure update mgt center with critical, security, Definition updates

[image]

Comment: very helpful and thanks for the level of details. how do you gather the current status of all VMs in the one subscription. Desktop analytics??